# USDZ file place above my head in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, usdz

When I load *.USDZ file in ARSCNView place object above my head. even I tried through apple provide sample demo “Handling3DInteractionAndUIControlsInAugmentedReality”.
I notice one thing is *.USDZ file formate content vast size bounding box by compare *.SCN file.

one more thing is .USDZ file place proper position in QLPreviewController. how can I achieve dynamic normalise *.USDZ file without scale property change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With usdz model, need set `scale = 0.005` before add to plane.

I found solution in GitHub: https://github.com/shu223/ARKit-Sampler

Comment: Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific detail answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Comment: What is the actual solution? I went to the github and searched for the text 0.005  and then looked at the issues and did not find anything. Please put the solution in your answer rather than a link.